# Unable to SetState() in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

`AppScreenC` will give all the installed apps in a `ListView`

```
class AppScreenC extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppScreenCState createState() => _AppScreenCState();
}

List<Application> apps;

getApps() async {
  if (apps == null) {
    apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(
        onlyAppsWithLaunchIntent: true,
        includeSystemApps: true,
        includeAppIcons: true);
    apps.sort((a, b) => a.appName.compareTo(b.appName));
  }
}
```

ListView with all the installed apps are getting displayed in screen. I'm trying to change the icons based on `onTap` event.

But clicking on a list, icons are not changing.

```
class _AppScreenCState extends State<AppScreenC> {
  final _app = <Application>[];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildApps();
  }

  Widget _buildApps() {
    getApps();
    return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      _app.addAll(apps);
      return _buildRow(_app[index]);
    });
  }

  Widget _buildRow(ApplicationWithIcon app) {
    bool selected = false;
    return ListTile(
      leading: Image.memory(app.icon, height: 40),
      trailing:
          Icon(selected ? Icons.check_circle : Icons.check_circle_outline),
      title: Text(app.appName),
      onTap: () {
        selected = !selected;
        // print("$selected");
        // print("${app.apkFilePath}");
        setState(() {});
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemCount:` missing in `ListView.Builder`

```
   Widget _buildApps() {
        getApps();
        return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          _app.addAll(apps);
          return _buildRow(_app[index]);
        }, itemCount: _app.length);
     }
```

Also,

```
class _AppScreenCState extends State<AppScreenC> {
bool selected = false; // this should be at the top as it will persist the value
```

Comment: How you are able to show List even if you don't add itemCount? I think my answer is correct? please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The `ListView` shows an `infinite` number of `items` if no `itemCount` is provided. So it is possible the `ListView` shows without the `itemCount`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but on this, it should be added as list will be fixed not endless

Comment: Ahh yeah, it definitely should be fixed in this case.

Comment: Yes, without `itemCount` `ListView` will be infinite. List will have all the items with `Range error` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
class _AppScreenCState extends State<AppScreenC> {

bool selected = false;

  Widget _buildRow(ApplicationWithIcon app) {
  //bool selected = false; not here
```